# How to use subsections in a powerdot presentation?

Tags: sectioning, presentations, powerdot

I'm using the powerdot class for create a `powerdot` presentation. According to the manual of the package I'm able to create a structure for the presentation using the `\section{}` command and it's very useful. I found that I can put a title to each slide and this could work as *sub-levels*. But what can I do when I need another level? I tried to use `\subsection` but it doesn't works.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass
[
    size=11pt,
    paper=screen,
    mode=present,   
    display=slidesnotes,
    style=sailor,
    nopagebreaks,
    pauseslide,
    clock
    ]{powerdot}

\pdsetup{
    palette=Wine
}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

    \section{About us}

    \begin{slide}{Organization}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam...
    \end{slide}

    \begin{slide}{Method}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
    \end{slide}

    \begin{note}{Personal note}
        A note...
    \end{note}

\section{Consequences}

\subsection{Economics}

\begin{slide}{Macroeconomics}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
\end{slide}

\begin{slide}{Microeconomics}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
\end{slide}

\subsection{Politics}

\begin{slide}{Subordination}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
\end{slide}
\end{document}
```

So, the question, is there a way to get a similar structure like in my MWE within powerdot?

Comment: That is not possible, use the class `beamer` instead.

Comment: @Herbert Thanks, it's a pity. Do you know if there is a way to create notes as in Powerdot but in beamer?

Comment: Beamer has the possibility of a handout which seems similar to notes.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the effect you're trying to achieve, you might be able to get what you want by combining the `slide=true` and `tocsection=false` options. For example:

```
\documentclass[style=sailor,size=12pt]{powerdot}

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}[toc=,bm=]{Overview}
This slide set covers the following topics:

\vspace{5mm}
\tableofcontents[content=sections]
\end{slide}

\section[slide=true]{Topic 1} 
\section[slide=true, tocsection=false]{Subtopic 1a} 
\section[slide=true, tocsection=false]{Subtopic 1b} 

\section[slide=true]{Topic 2} 
\section[slide=true, tocsection=false]{Subtopic 2a} 
\section[slide=true, tocsection=false]{Subtopic 2b} 

\end{document}
```

will create six section divider slides.  However, only "Topic 1" and "Topic 2" will appear in the overview, and Subtopics only appear in the table of contents when you are looking at a slide inside the corresponding Topic.

For my use case, this is equivalent to creating subsections, and vastly preferable to rewriting my entire slide set in Beamer.